# Publish web app without webjobs

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, publish, azure-webjobs

In visual studio 2015, I am deploying a site with three webjobs by right-clicking the web app and publishing (stop judging me! I know you do terrible things too!). I have multiple publish profiles (.pubxml) set up; Is there a way in one of the profiles to publish *only* the website/app and skip the webjobs?

Comment: @PeterBons - https://damianbrady.com.au/2018/02/01/friends-dont-let-friends-right-click-publish/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, find `<ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>` and change value to `True`.

Note that if you have already published webjobs to website, this settings won't remove them.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a feature or a bug :D but your suggestion works so I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan should be a feature for us to leverage, as the webjob will be uploaded to app_data folder once the web app is deployed with this `false` setting.